# SqlException: Violation of ****** constraint '******'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '******'. The duplicate key value is ******

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

When trying to insert users into the AspNetUsers table using EF, I got the following error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> SqlException: Violation of ****** constraint '******'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object '******'. The duplicate key value is ******.
>   The statement has been terminated.

That error is verbatim (it actually showed the asterisks).  Before inserting the users, I explicitly deleted them, so I don't know why I'm getting this error.

Code to delete users

```
            foreach (var user in globalUsers)
            {
                if (rdb.Users.Any(u => u.Email == user.Email))
                {
                    var existingUserInDb = rdb.Users.First(u => u.Email == user.Email);
                    rdb.Users.Remove(existingUserInDb);
                    await rdb.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
```

Code to add new users

```
            foreach (var gu in globalUsers)
            {
                rdb.Users.Add(gu);
                await rdb.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried commit  after deleting? This is because you tried  same primary key insertion.

Comment: For the exception containing masked values, see if using [EnableSensitiveDataLogging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.enablesensitivedatalogging) method helps.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the following:

- When adding the users, I had set the User IDs explicitly
- We were using soft deletes, so deleting the existing user wasn't actually deleting it
- ASP.NET/EF didn't read the soft delete, and so I was inserting another user that had the same User ID as the soft deleted user

I solved the issue by creating a new User ID when inserting the users.

```
        foreach (var gu in globalUsers)
        {
            gu.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            rdb.Users.Add(gu);
            await rdb.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```